# create new javascript object from within a version of itself

Tags: javascript

I forked a JSfiddle from this blog post (just for fun on a Tuesday evening...)
http://boundary.com/blog/2012/07/03/building-node-diagrams-in-html5/

And have been trying to create a linked `new Node()` every time I double click one. My fiddle is here
http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/cGzCe/4/

I was trying not to mess with the library at first, but the fiddle includes (in resources) an altered version where I added support for the dblclick event.

Anyway, to the point! I'm passing in a function to be run on the event, and it does work in when double clicking on `firstNode` but I'd need to keep re-adding the event to each new created node / reference the create function somehow which would guess us into a loop.

```
var create = function() {
  var node = new Node({
    title: 'Node',
    stage: stage,
    w: NODE_DIMENSIONS.w,
    h: NODE_DIMENSIONS.h,
    x: 100,
    y: 100
  }).attach();
  new Segment({
    h: 5,
    stage: stage,
    origin: this,
    destination: node
  }).attach();
}
var firstNode = new Node({
    title: 'Node',
    stage: stage,
    w: NODE_DIMENSIONS.w,
    h: NODE_DIMENSIONS.h,
    x: 350,
    y: 50,
    events: {
        dblclick: create
    }
}).attach();
```

I feel like I should be looking to modify the prototype function for the double click event but just got a bit lost. Does anyone a) know what I'm talking about? and b) can you help. It's not client work or anything, but I'd just like to know!

I've had a quick scan for duplicated, but as you might tell from my badly worded question title, I'm not entirely sure how to phrase my search!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to accomplish this would be to add the `dblclick` event to the created node. You should be able to extend the Node class to do this automatically, but I'm not sure it's necessary.

```
var create = function() {

  var node = new Node({
    title: 'Node',
    stage: stage,
    w: NODE_DIMENSIONS.w,
    h: NODE_DIMENSIONS.h,
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    events:{ // add the event to the created node. 
      dblclick: create
    }
  }).attach();

  new Segment({
    h: 5,
    stage: stage,
    origin: this,
    destination: node
  }).attach();

  //nodes.push(node);
}
```

for positioning the newly created nodes, I would suggest that it be relative to the node they are spawned from:

```
var create = function() {
  var ancestor = $(event.target); // get the element that was double clicked
  var top = ancestor.position().top;  // and its position
  var left = ancestor.position().left;

  var node = new Node({
    title: 'Node',
    stage: stage,
    w: NODE_DIMENSIONS.w,
    h: NODE_DIMENSIONS.h,
    x: left + 100,        //new position relative to the parent.
    y: top + 100,
    events:{
      dblclick: create
    }
  }).attach();

  new Segment({
    h: 5,
    stage: stage,
    origin: this,
    destination: node
  }).attach();

  //nodes.push(node);
}
```

Comment: it seems i've been a bit silly ;o) thanks! i don't know why i hadn't tried that first. just assumed it would cause an issue, but it makes total sense. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine but the issue is the new nodes are overlapping on each other since in create function you have your x and y at 100 to create new nodes.

so I used math.random to generate random x,y positions to new nodes

here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cGzCe/7/)

You should be generating new nodes positions and names randomly according to your needs

Comment: i should have mentioned that i'll get to the random bits in time. i just wanted to work out the 'continuous' creation stuff first. thanks very much though!